# What is function of this complicated circuit?

Tags: digital-logic

Here is my task:

a) Explain principle of working of circuit below. Draw waveforms of voltage 
at points A, B, C, D and Q, as well as capacitors voltage waveforms.

b) What is minimum time constant of charging of C3 (ie value of resistance R6) so that voltage waveform of point Q are rectangular pulses

It is known: R1, R2, R3 (R2=R3), R4, R5, R6, C1=C2=C3, 5R1>>R2 and R1>>R3. Threshold voltage equals VDD/2.

[image]

Any suggestion?
I did nothing because I have no idea how to start :( I'm beginner in Digital electronics. In analog electronics and in circuit theory, there are well known methods for solving circuits, but what to do here? I'm really stuck :(

EDIT: This is not homework question. I don't have final result. This was on my exam. I didn't solve it on exam and I'm trying to figure out what is solution to this problem. Every suggestion is welcome, I want to pass exam next time :)

Comment: I love the smell of burning homework in the morning. What have you done to solve this, and where are you stuck?

Comment: Here is a hint: digital circuits are simply overdriven analogue circuits. Look up unbuffered CMOS gates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Divide and conquer

[image]

What does each part do?

Comment: This is not an answer.

Comment: @pipe The general rule of this forum is NOT to answer homework questions but to give guidance.

Comment: Where can I find those general rules? They're not in the help center at least. This is the first time I've seen someone posting a _question_ without showing the resulting solution. If you don't want to answer homework questions, that's fine, but my understanding is that this website is about good _answers_ to good questions. Trying to answer with a question just adds more noise to the search engines.

Comment: @pipe, sometimes the best way to teach is for the teacher to ask questions of the student. This idea [is not new](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Socratic_method).

Comment: Hello, thanks for answer. I would say that second part is High pass filter, third is inverter and fourth looks like NE555. I'm not sure about first part. Essentially, you want to say that in order to understand "complete" circuit, I should first understand it's parts (stages) like you devided, right? But then it's not clear to me: Let's say I analysed first part of this circuit (first division of picture in your answer) and found voltage waveform at point B. (I will continue in next comment)

Comment: ... If I then connect second part to it (high pass filter), it would "interact" with previous stage and, logically, waveform of point B I got when analyzed first stage on it's own will CHANGE?

Comment: No, the voltage at point B is completely determined by the gate that is driving it. The load connection will not change it.

Comment: @Igor  (2) yes, but look up differentiator (3) yes (4) yes but look at the values of the ladder resistors for the comparators. I've divided the parts into functional blocks. The output from the first block is the input to the second and so on. So if you know what is output at B (for example) you know what you must input to the next stage.

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have most of it, so here are some additional hints regarding the first part.

Clearly, points A and B are driven by digital gates, so each one can only be in one of two states: connected to Vdd ("high") or connected to Vss ("low"). Furthermore, point B is simply going to be point A inverted.

Therefore, you only have two states to consider: How does the circuit behave when point A is high, and how does it behave when point A is low? What happens when it makes a transition from one state to the other?